# Base class's class procedure should instantiate a descendant's object?

Tags: delphi

Why in the code below, do I get the "Failed" message rather than "Succeeded"

Background: I like to have class procedures that instantiate their owner object, do something, and then free it.

However, this approach doesn't work if I have a descendant object:

Any suggestions on how to provide class procedures in a base class that can be called as a child?  Am I thinking about this wrongly?

```
Type
  TBase = class(TObject)
    Protected
       Procedure Proc1; Virtual;
    Public
       Class Procedure MyClassProc;
  end;

  Class Procedure TBase.MyClassProc;
  Var
    Base: TBase;
  begin
    Base := TBase.Create;
    Base.Proc1;
    Base.Free;
  end;

  Procedure TBase.Proc1;
  begin
    Assert(FALSE, 'Failed');
  end;

type
   TChild = class(TBase)
   protected
      Procedure Proc1; Override;
   end;

   Procedure TChild.Proc1;
   begin
     ShowMessage('Succeeded');
   end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TChild.MyClassProc;
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it easily with meta-programmation! Just change "TBase.Create" to "Self.Create" "self" represents the current class, it doesn't metter if is a base o a child class.

```
Type
  TBase = class(TObject)
    Protected
       Procedure Proc1; Virtual;
    Public
       Class Procedure MyClassProc;
  end;

  Class Procedure TBase.MyClassProc;
  Var
    MyObject: TBase;
  begin
    // MyObject := TBase.Create;
    MyObject := Self.Create; // The Magic goes here, self is the class that's calling this method, in this case, TChild }
    MyObject.Proc1;
    MyObject.Free;
  end;

  Procedure TBase.Proc1;
  begin
    Assert(FALSE, 'Failed');
  end;

type
   TChild = class(TBase)
   protected
      Procedure Proc1; Override;
   end;

   Procedure TChild.Proc1;
   begin
     ShowMessage('Succeeded');
   end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  TChild.MyClassProc;
end;
```

Comment: +1. I still don't like the whole idea, but at least this comes with the minimum of additional code, and has no danger of screwing up by forgetting to provide the overridden helper function.

Answer (score 1):

Strip everything down to the bare minimum, and you will see that you only ever create a `TBase` instance, so consequently only `TBase.Proc1()` will ever be called. If you want to have `TChild.Proc1()` be called you need to create a `TChild` instance and let polymorphism work its magic.

There could however be better ways to achieve your goal (whatever it is) than to have a class method create an object instance to do something. Maybe you should clarify your question.

Comment: @mghie: Hi! In early days I got a question like that! Let me explain: I Made a Base form to list some especials properties in the code inspect, with various inherited forms, one of that properties was the kind of form which was staticaly recorded in the .FRM file and I needed no know what kind of form was it to register it in my custon form factory. The logic of registering was in the Base Form's class for share with his childs. The only one way I fould to retrieve the form kind was instantiate it and then get it from the form "object". Regards.

Answer (score 1):

Here it is

Add

```
TBase = class;
TBaseClass = class of TBase;

TBase = class(TObject)
protected
  class function GetBaseClass: TBaseClass; virtual;

function TBase.GetBaseClass: TBaseClass;
begin
  Result := TBase;
end;

TChild = class(TBase)
protected
  class function GetBaseClass: TBaseClass; override;

function TChild.GetBaseClass: TBaseClass;
begin
  Result := TChild;
end;
```

Change

from

```
Base := TBase.Create;
```

to

```
Base := GetBaseClass.Create;
```

Enjoy your work

Cheer

A Pham

Comment: That's an obvious workaround, but it still begs the question: why would one do it this way? Why the class method, why not a free function? Why have a class hierarchy **at all**?

Comment: @mghie - I have used a model similar to this in the past, but with a class registry to determine what class to create at runtime, or to "clone" the current class.

Comment: @skamradt: Polymorphism and class methods don't go together for me. if an instance is to be created anyway, way not pass it around instead of the class? As for *Clone()* - this would not need to be a class method, as an instance is there to be cloned?